# Call an executable with quotes at specific positions

Tags: powershell

I want to call an executable from a PowerShell script that requires quotes at specific positions in the argument list. Although I found similar questions I did not find a solution at all.

This is what the command must look like on the command line:

```
reptool.exe --profile="C:\My profile"
```

The parameter value ("C:\Profiles...") is supposed to be generated dynamically using a variable:

```
$repToolProfile = "C:\My profile"
```

This is what I have already tried:

```
&"reptool.exe" --profile=$repToolProfile
```

Fails as the argument is given as `"--profile=C:\My profile"` (quotes around the whole argument).

```
&"reptool.exe" --profile="$repToolProfile"
```

Fails as the argument is given as `"--profile=C:\My profile"` (quotes around the whole argument, same as above).

```
&"reptool.exe" "--profile=`"$repToolProfile`"
```

Fails as the argument is given as `"--profile="C:\My profile""` (quotes around the whole argument **and** the value).

I cannot use single quotes or the "verbatim operator" (`--%`) as I have to use a PowerShell variable, neither I can use `Start-Process` as it is called asynchroneously (even when I use the `-Wait` parameter. Also I want to check the exit code. I don't want to convert my arguments to Base64.

Comment: Try this: `&"reptool.exe" @{'--profile=' = ('"{0}"' -f $repToolProfile)}`

Comment: Does not work. The argument is expanded to `System.Collections.Hashtable`.

Comment: ``&"reptool.exe" '--%' "--profile=`"$repToolProfile`""``

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$command = '& "reptool.exe" --% ' + "--profile=`"$repToolProfile`"
Invoke-Expression $command
```